# Finding words with certain attributes, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: search, adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to find words (similar to the way you can look for certain words with Ctrl + F) with certain attributes, eg. Bolded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with on-board means. Theoretically, it may be possible using a plug-in, but it is not sure whether Adobe would certify such a plug-in for Reader. For Acrobat (Standard or Pro), there would be no certification issue.

Comment: Where would i find such a plugin?

Comment: You might have to find a developer doing it, as I don't think there is something in that line generally available.